# Mathematical logic problem on Mr. M

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic

Although this question is posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2066927/if-mr-m-is-guilty-then-no-witness-is-lying-unless-he-is-afraid),still i am posting this because the solution present there is copied from [here](https://gateoverflow.in/20939/tifr2012-a-2) and also i want to know flaw in my approach.

### Question

> If Mr.M is guilty, then no witness is lying unless he is afraid. There is a witness who is afraid. Which of the following statements is true?
>
> 1. Mr.M is guilty.
> 2. Mr.M is not guilty.
> 3. From these facts one cannot conclude that Mr.M is guilty.
> 4. There is a witness who is lying.
> 5. No witness is lying.
>
> Hint: Formulate the problem using the following predicates
>
> $G$ − Mr.M is guilty
>
> $W(x)$ − $x$ is a witness
>
> $L(x)$ − $x$ is lying
>
> $A(x)$ − $x$ is afraid

### My Approach

As we know that 
$p \rightarrow q \equiv \text{q unless p'}$

I can write the entire sentence into logical equation as

$(G\rightarrow (W(x) \wedge L(x))) \text{unless } A(x)$

$\equiv A(x) ^{'} \rightarrow (G\rightarrow (W(x) \wedge L(x)))$

Now it is given that $A(x)$ is true hence LHS becomes false and hene entire 
statement becomes true and hence it is independent of RHS .So option $3$ is true.

Am i doing right?
please help

Comment: It is not given that "$A(x)$ is true". The statement doesn't even make sense without quantifying $x$. What is given is "$\exists x\colon W(x) \wedge A(x)$".

Answer (score 1):

Your formulation lacks quantifiers. The given statements are

1. $G\rightarrow \bigg( \forall x\colon W(x) \rightarrow (\neg A(x) \rightarrow \neg L(x)) \bigg)$
2. $\exists x\colon W(x)\wedge A(x)$.

Using $P\to Q \equiv \neg P \vee Q$ we may write the first statement as
$$G\rightarrow \bigg( \forall x\colon \neg W(x) \vee A(x) \vee \neg L(x) \bigg).$$

Define $Q \equiv \forall x\colon \neg W(x) \vee A(x) \vee \neg L(x)$, so that we have $G\to Q$. Given $G\to Q$ the only conclusion about $G$ we can make is that when $Q$ is false, $G$ has to be false (since $G\to Q\equiv \neg Q\to\neg G$). Hence, we can never conclude that $G$ is true from this. But we also can not show that $Q$ is false, since our only known person $x$ does not falsify $Q$. Hence, we can not determine the truth value of $G$.

Comment: okk..but what is wrong in this  $(G \rightarrow \forall x (A(x)^{'}\rightarrow (W(x) \wedge L(x))) )$ ?

Comment: This reads "If Mr. M is guilty, everybody who is not afraid is a witness and lying", which is not what is stated in the problem.

Comment: okk got it ..thanks ..but can you please explain how can you use $2$ in $1$ to get the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

> If Mr.M is guilty, then no witness is lying unless he is afraid. There is a witness who is afraid.

If Mr.M is guilty, then there does not exist a witness who is lying and not afraid.

$$G\to \neg\exists x~(W(x)\wedge L(x)\wedge\neg A(x))$$

---

There exists a witness who is afraid:  $$\exists y~(W(y)\wedge A(y))$$

Comment: how did you use "unless" ?? IMO..$p \rightarrow q $ implies $\text{ q unless}\,\,\, p'$

Comment: *Context* is important @laura .  "*None* are lying unless afraid", states that if anyone is lying then they must be afraid, so therefore no one can be lying and not afraid.

Answer (score 0):

> $(G\rightarrow (W(x) \wedge L(x))) \text{unless } A(x)$

No. You're parsing this incorrectly. The being afraid part is just about the witnesses, so the whole statement is a conditional with Mr.M being guilty as the antecedent, and the rest (the bit about the witnesses) as the consequent, so we get:

$G \rightarrow $ "no witness is lying unless he is afraid"

OK, so now we need to translate "no witness is lying unless he is afraid". Again, this is about witnesses, i.e. being a witness is the subject term (that what the claim is about), while the "lying unless afraid" is the predicate term, i.e. what we say about those witnesses. Finally, you need a universal quantifier in here, since this is about *all* witnesses. That is, we can paraphrase this sentence as:

"all witnesses are not lying unless afraid"

Hence, the general form is:

$\forall x (W(x) \rightarrow$ "$x$ is not lying unless $x$ is afraid")

And now you finally use the trick with the unless (I always think of "P unless Q" as "P if not Q"):

$G \rightarrow (W(x) \rightarrow (\neg A(x) \rightarrow \neg L(x)))$